# Can't export OSM base map in QGIS 2.18

Tags: openstreetmap, export, error, qgis-2.18

Every time I tried to export map with OSM map I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\py_tiled_layer\tilelayer.py", line 319, in draw
self.drawTilesOnTheFly(renderContext, self.tiles)
File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\py_tiled_layer\tilelayer.py", line 397, in drawTilesOnTheFly
tile_ds.SetProjection(str(transform.sourceCrs().toWkt()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetProjection'
```

I export the map by the regular way- in the map composer. The  installsion process of QGIS 2.18 was just fine without any error message.

I don't understand what is my mistake?

Comment: Make sure to set **layer** and **project** CRS to EPSG:3857.

Comment: I work with EPSG:2039  CRS

Comment: It might be that you run into a bug in the plugin when reprojection is needed in the map composer.